# How to insert values into auto identity column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, mysql-workbench

I would like to insert values into mysql innodb table `Auto_Increment` column.

I am loading some data from an old table to new table which has an identity, and need to preserve the existing values from the old table, so I need to preserve the existing `Id` values, but keep the column `Auto_Increment` for new values.

In MS T-SQL, I would start my `insert` query script with `SET SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON` and end the query with `SET SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF`.

How can I do the same in MySQL?

Comment: Why? Is the value MySQL provides automatically not suitable?

Comment: Why is the column an Auto Identity if you need to insert into it?

Comment: Auto-identity columns are filled in automatically by MySQL.  If you want a different number, you should maintain a separate field.

Comment: i wanted to load some data from other table to new table which has an identity, so i want to use the existing values from old table.

Comment: This is a pretty common need when loading sample data or moving data from one database to another. I really don't understand why this is marked as "not a question".

Comment: Agree with the previous 2 comments. They are nieve and clearly not based on experience with migrating real data or building tests for development (that must be run on staging and production with the same data).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just do as usual:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(auto_inc_field, other_field) VALUES(8547, 'some value');
```

If the values are comming from another table, you may use:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(auto_inc_field, other_field)
SELECT auto_inc_field, other_field FROM other_table;
```

Comment: And if you import data, there you go with a brand new id value that will generate if your integer in auto_inc_field is 0 or NULL.  "violation of foreign key constraint xxx". This answer deserves being downvoted rather than the question...

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this just like me, and you have inserted rows with an ID. You can manually set the auto_inc_field using 'ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT = 10' - where 10 is the next value to be used for an inserted row.

Comment: With PostgreSQL you likewise have to reset the auto-increment field.

Comment: @MartinBlore Updated answer to this now 4 years later.  From the documentation on version 5.7 `When you insert any other value into an AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to that value and the sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the largest column value.`