# MySQL - INSERT INTO Table With a New ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I want to copy a row from one to the other. However they both use an auto incrementing ID number as the primary key which is preventing me from copying a row if the ID already exists in the other table.

What I want to do is:

```
INSERT INTO tableB SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE ID = 1
```

What I was thinking might be possible would be to store the row as a variable, temporarily set the ID to be blank, and then it will be assigned the next highest number once inserted into the new table?

Is something like this possible?

Edit:

Columns

ID, Deal_ID, Redeemed_At, Wowcher_Code, Deal_Title, Customer_Name, House_Name_Number, Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2, City, County, Postcode, Email, Phone, Date_of_Birth, Custom_Field, Marketing_Permission, Product_Name, Product_Options

Comment: Can you post columns of your table?

Comment: also have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108003/how-to-insert-values-into-auto-identity-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use * (all columns) in this case  .. you must explicitally set the columns you need eg:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM tableA 
WHERE ID = 1
```

avoinding the ID columns

Comment: Perhaps you meant "cannot" rather than "can"?

Comment: Of all the answers this worked best as I needed to have the list of columns in brackets too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just select the columns without the ID.

```
INSERT INTO tableB SELECT name,age,any_other_column FROM tableA WHERE ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace asterisks with fields list withouth ID

```
INSERT INTO tableB SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3...FieldXX FROM tableA WHERE ID = 1
```