# Is it possible to insert a specific primary key with autoincrement in MySQL using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I need to insert specific numeric values in an auto increment defined column using hibernate.

Without specifying the value it behaves as expected but I need to insert some values that come from a migration and cannot change them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried saving object with manually provided? it is supposed to use provided id, when no id is provided it generates the id. If there is any error please provide log

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108003/how-to-insert-values-into-auto-identity-column-in-mysql)